# perform an API call with Ajax instead of cUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, owncloud

I have a service running on the same domain of my website that expose an API. I have managed to call the API using cUrl but I'd like to move it to some vanilla js/jquery.

My actual code is:

```
$postData = array(
    'userid' => $userid,
    'password' => $password,
    'email' => $userid
);

//creo utente base
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admin:password@xxx.com/cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
```

I have tried with a simple ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://admin:password@xxx.com/cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users',
    method: 'post',
    data: {userid:'a',password:'b',email:'c'},
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){
    //handle the results
});
```

or this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://mydomain/cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa(admin:password));
        },
        method: 'post',
        data: {userid:'mario@mari.com',password:'Annapurna1',email:'mario@mari.com'},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

but i get a 401 error that is "unhautorized". this means that the credentials provided in the url are not valid. But if I make a post request with the same url using Postman it passes the authorization.

What am I missing here?

Comment: if it's working via postman, you can use postman's code generator to directly generate the js code for it :D

Comment: are you sure everything is ok on your types ? ( string VS int )

Comment: @singebatteur there are no typos in the code.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar postman will end up with my same code. The issue anyway is in the url and how jquery is posting it not in the ajax request syntax

Comment: 401 is pretty clear message. When using postman do you use basic authorization or just posting the login credentials, cause its not clear from your code? In your second attempt, where are admin and password vars defined when you try the basic authorization?

Comment: @AngelDeykov in postman it works with both: url and basic auth. In my code it doesn't. Note the typo I had in my edit about the quotes around admin:user. Also, if I try to use the code generated by postman it doesn't work either

Comment: you have any js errors ?

Comment: @AngelDeykov obviously no, since the call is performed and the 401 is returned by the destination endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error I was getting was completely misleading.

I solved by adding `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` that is used to send the parameters to the API simulating a form.
Adding this resolved the issue even if the error message was related to the wrong authentication (the username and the password used to log in) and not to the parameters passed to the API.

So my final code is

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://mydomain/cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa('admin:password'));
        },
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        method: 'post',
        data: {userid:'john@gmail.com',password:'userpassword',email:'john@gmail.com'},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```